# How can I fix the Mingw-w64 C++ "No such file or directory" error in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, header, mingw

I am using the Mingw-w64 compiler with Netbeans IDE. I downloaded a project from GitHub and added it as an external library (added the source folders to sources and headers folders to includes under project structure). However I am getting an "No such file or directory" error.

The project structure is:

[image: Project Structure]

The code in Main.cpp is:

[image: Main.cpp]

The error I got is:

```
Desktop/ExternalLibraryFolder/src/ExternalSourcesFolder/ExternalSourcesSubfolder3/source3.cpp:5:10: fatal error: ExternalHeadersFolder/ExternalHeadersSubfolder3/header3.hpp: No such file or directory
    #include "ExternalHeadersFolder/ExternalHeadersSubfolder3/header3.hpp"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Please add the code as text, instead of linking to a picture.

Comment: Try to replace `<header>` with `"header"`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What is your compile command?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I tried your recommendations however I still getting the same error. So I decided to provide more details in order you be able to provide me with more suggestions.

I want to code a software using a text based interface (TUI). I found FTXUI in GitHub and want to use it, that project repository structure is:

```
FTXUI-master
├───.github
├───doc
├───examples
│   ├───component
│   ├───dom
│   ├───html
│   └───util
├───include
│   └───ftxui
│       ├───component
│       ├───dom
│       ├───screen
│       └───util
├───other
└───src
    └───ftxui
        ├───component
        ├───dom
        └───screen
```

I downloaded it to my computer.

I am using Netbeans 8.2 RC and Mingw-w64 compiler, first I tried to add the includes and the sources in Netbeans adding the "include" and
"src" from FTXUI to the include and source file paths in Netbeans, like this:

```
CppApplication
│
│
├───HeaderFiles
│   └include
│    └───ftxui
│        ├───component
│        ├───dom
│        ├───screen
│        └───util
│
├───SourceFiles
│    └──main.cpp
│    └src
│     └───ftxui
│         ├───component
│         ├───dom
│         ├───screen
│         └───util
├───TestFiles
└───ImportantFiles
```

The main.cpp file content is:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "ftxui/dom/elements.hpp"
#include "ftxui/screen/screen.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  using namespace ftxui; 

  Element document =
    hbox({
      text(L"left")   | border,
      text(L"middle") | border | flex,
      text(L"right")  | border,
    });

  auto screen = Screen::Create(
    Dimension::Full(),       // Width
    Dimension::Fit(document) // Height
  );
  Render(screen, document);
  std::cout << screen.ToString() << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

The output I got was:

cd 'C:\Users\CurrentUser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_2'
C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2' "/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe make.exe[2]: Entering directory` /c/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f/checkbox.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f/checkbox.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f/checkbox.o ../../../Desktop/FTXUI-master/FTXUI-master/src/ftxui/component/checkbox.cpp
../../../Desktop/FTXUI-master/FTXUI-master/src/ftxui/component/checkbox.cpp:5:10: fatal error: ftxui/component/checkbox.hpp: No such file or directory
#include "ftxui/component/checkbox.hpp"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/_ext/3a58e87f/checkbox.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2' make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2 make.exe[1]: Leaving directory` /c/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)